# Quantum channel between two states with inaccessible reference - when can it be done?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation, information-theory

Suppose I have a pair of bipartite states $\rho_{AR}$ and $\sigma_{BR}$. $R$ is a reference system that we do not have access to.

It is clear that we cannot always have a channel $N_{A\rightarrow B}$ such that $(N\otimes I_R)(\rho_{AR}) = \sigma_{AR}$. If this were the case, we could, for example, generate entanglement through a local operation on $A$ and $B$ which is not possible.

Given a $\rho_{AR}$ and $\sigma_{BR}$, is there a way to know if there exists a channel $N_{A\rightarrow B}$ with the desired property?

Comment: just to be clear, you are asking under what conditions, given $\rho_{AR}$ and $\sigma_{BR}$, there is a channel $N$ such that $(N\otimes I_R)(\rho_{AR})=\sigma_{AR}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

One necessary (but I doubt sufficient) condition is that the partial trace that removes everything but the reference system must be the same for the initial and final state. First, assume that $N$ is trace-preserving for system $A$. Then, using some decomposition
$$\rho_{AR}=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}|k\rangle_A\langle l|\otimes |m\rangle_R\langle n|,$$
we have
\begin{aligned}
\text{Tr}_B(\sigma_{BR})&=\text{Tr}_B[(N\otimes \mathbb{I})\rho_{AR}]\\
&=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}\text{Tr}_B[N(|k\rangle_A\langle l|)\otimes |m\rangle_R\langle n|]\\
&=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}\text{Tr}[N(|k\rangle_A\langle l|) ]|m\rangle_R\langle n|\\
&=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}\text{Tr}[|k\rangle_A\langle l| ]|m\rangle_R\langle n|\\
&=\text{Tr}_A(\rho_{AR}).
\end{aligned}
If $N$ is not normalized, then the trace of $\rho_{AR}$ and $\sigma_{BR}$ will be different, so they won't both be "states." If you're ok with that then we get stuck at the step
$$\text{Tr}_B(\sigma_{BR})=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}\text{Tr}[N(|k\rangle_A\langle l|) ]|m\rangle_R\langle n|$$ and the relationships between pairs of related states will be even more complicated.

---

In general, we can use the same basis labels to express either system $A$ or $B$, because we can always extend one basis if the other has a larger dimension. In that sense, we can always write
$$\sigma_{BR}=\sum_{klmn}s_{klmn}|k\rangle\langle l|\otimes |m\rangle_R\langle n|$$ and drop the basis label for system $B$. The channel then necessitates
$$\sum_{klmn}s_{klmn}|k\rangle\langle l|\otimes |m\rangle_R\langle n|=\sum_{klmn}p_{klmn}N(|k\rangle\langle l|)\otimes |m\rangle_R\langle n|,$$ so the two states must obey the mutual relationship
$$\sum_{kl}s_{klmn}|k\rangle\langle l|=\sum_{kl}p_{klmn}N(|k\rangle\langle l|)$$ for all $m$ and $n$ (this trivially includes cases when $p_{klmn}$ or $s_{klmn}$ vanish for a particular pair of $m$ and $n$ values). That is the necessary and sufficient condition that you are looking for.

---

Can we make more sense of this requirement? Say we know everything about our channel, such that we know how it acts on all basis states
$$N(|k\rangle \langle l|)=\sum_{k^\prime l^\prime}n^{(kl)}_{k^\prime l^\prime}|k^\prime\rangle \langle l^\prime|.$$ Then the necessary and sufficient condition is that
$$s_{klmn}=\sum_{k^\prime l^\prime}p_{k^\prime l^\prime mn}n^{(k^\prime l^\prime)}_{kl}$$ for all $k$, $l$, $m$, and $n$. For every state $\rho_{AB}$, there is a corresponding paired state $\sigma_{BR}$. The converse is not true, unless you can invert the relationship $s_{klmn}=\sum_{k^\prime l^\prime}p_{k^\prime l^\prime mn}n^{(k^\prime l^\prime)}_{kl}$, which will only happen for certain channels $N$. Which channels? That is a good question, beyond the scope here! Possibly related to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20871/15820).